# Google maps V3 API highway visibility

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-styling

I'm trying to build a kiosk application with vehicles as markers on a map. The zoom and centering is set automatically when the marker coordinates are loaded from the server (there's no user interaction). I'd like to see all the highways on the map (i.e. highways that the markers/vehicles are positioned/driving on), but Google maps decides which highways are visible at each zoom level.

Does anyone know of a way to force the display of all highways, or display the highways of zoom level 6 on zoom level 7, etc.?

I've tried: `{
            "featureType": "road.highway",
            "elementType": "all",
            "stylers": [
              { "visibility": "on" },
              { "hue": "#ff0000" }
            ]
        }`
to no avail.

Comment: You can't control at what zoom level things appear on the map. What you can do though is to prevent users from zooming out/in at certain zoom levels.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to live with it